# Combine xarray Datasets on stacked coordinate

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have two datasets, where they share a coordinate. But, in the first set that coordinate is stacked. I want to merge the two dataset, so that the second set is also indexed by the stacked coordinate.

I've managed to get this working by manually restructuring the second dataset, but feel like there has to be a better way to do this in xarray. Any ideas?

#### Example data setup

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# set up dataset A
seed = 33
np.random.seed(seed)
a = np.arange(3)
b = np.arange(4)

shape = [len(a), len(b)]
c = np.arange(np.prod(shape)).reshape(shape)
x = np.random.random(shape)
y = np.random.random(shape)

dataset_a = xr.Dataset.from_dict({
    'dims': ['a', 'b'],
    'coords': {
        'a': {'dims': 'a', 'data': a},
        'b': {'dims': 'b', 'data': b},
        'c': {'dims': ['a', 'b'], 'data': c}
    },
    'data_vars': {
        'x': {'dims': ['a', 'b'], 'data': x},
        'y': {'dims': ['a', 'b'], 'data': y}
    }
})

# set up dataset_b
np.random.seed(seed)
mask = np.random.choice([True, False], shape)
c_new = c[mask]
z = np.random.random(len(c_new))

dataset_b = xr.Dataset.from_dict({
    'dims': 'c',
    'coords': {
        'c': {'dims': 'c', 'data': c_new}
    },
    'data_vars': {
        'z': {'dims': 'c', 'data': z}
    }
})
```

#### Datasets to merge

```py
In [15]: dataset_a
Out[15]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (a: 3, b: 4)
Coordinates:
  * a        (a) int64 0 1 2
  * b        (b) int64 0 1 2 3
    c        (a, b) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
Data variables:
    x        (a, b) float64 0.2485 0.45 0.4109 0.2603 ... 0.4866 0.965 0.3934
    y        (a, b) float64 0.07956 0.3514 0.1636 ... 0.2478 0.6228 0.1424

In [16]: dataset_b
Out[16]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (c: 6)
Coordinates:
  * c        (c) int64 0 2 3 4 8 11
Data variables:
    z        (c) float64 0.01966 0.9533 0.6805 0.4866 0.965 0.3934
```

#### Attempt at merging with `ds.merge`

When I use `xr.Dataset.merge()` the original coordinate `c` is overwritten by the new version, without stack.

```py
In [17]: dataset_c = dataset_a.merge(dataset_b)
Out[17]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (a: 3, b: 4, c: 6)
Coordinates:
  * a        (a) int64 0 1 2
  * b        (b) int64 0 1 2 3
  * c        (c) int64 0 2 3 4 8 11
Data variables:
    x        (a, b) float64 0.2485 0.45 0.4109 0.2603 ... 0.4866 0.965 0.3934
    y        (a, b) float64 0.07956 0.3514 0.1636 ... 0.2478 0.6228 0.1424
    z        (c) float64 0.01966 0.9533 0.6805 0.4866 0.965 0.3934
```

#### Attempt #2 - manual alignment

Should I be doing something like creating `z` filled with nan, and then use `xr.Dataset.where()` to add the values from `dataset_b`?

```py
dataset_d = dataset_a.copy()

z_new = np.full_like(dataset_d['x'].values.flatten(), np.nan)
z_shape = dataset_d['x'].shape
z_dims = dataset_d['x'].dims

for i in dataset_d['c'].values.flatten():
    if i in dataset_b['c'].values.flatten():
        z_new[i] = dataset_b.sel(c = i)['z'].values.flatten()

z_new = z_new.reshape(z_shape)

dataset_d['z'] = (z_dims, z_new)
```

```py
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (a: 3, b: 4)
Coordinates:
  * a        (a) int64 0 1 2
  * b        (b) int64 0 1 2 3
    c        (a, b) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
Data variables:
    x        (a, b) float64 0.2485 0.45 0.4109 0.2603 ... 0.4866 0.965 0.3934
    y        (a, b) float64 0.07956 0.3514 0.1636 ... 0.2478 0.6228 0.1424
    z        (a, b) float64 0.01966 nan 0.9533 0.6805 ... 0.965 nan nan 0.3934
```

This works, but is there a cleaner/faster way to do this?

Comment: This is an awesome question, and thanks so much for the great [mre]! I updated the title and restructured a bit just to make the question (in my opinion) a bit easier to read. Please feel free to [roll it back](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74204083/revisions) or [make further edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74204083/edit) if you'd like or if you think I've misrepresented your intention anywhere. Hope this is helpful!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado thank you! If there’s anything I’ve learned (here and elsewhere) is the value of a minimal reproducible example to convey problems & ideas. And thanks for polishing my post ☺️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

great question! it's actually much easier than this. using xarray's [More Advanced Indexing](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#more-advanced-indexing) rules, passing a `DataArray` to a selection method (`.sel`, `.isel`, `.loc`, `.interp`, ...) will reshape the array by using the selection array's *values* as the selector but reshaping to conform to the shape of the selector's *coordinates* in the output.

So in the absence of any mismatched coordinates, you can just do this:

```py
dataset_b.sel(c=dataset_a.c)
```

In your case, you have some levels in `dataset_a.c` which are not present in `dataset_b.c`. To fully align them, you could do any number of things to align a with b or visa versa. I'll stick with a left join on `dataset_a.c`'s levels, by using [`xarray.Dataset.reindex`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.reindex.html):

```py
all_c_levels = np.unique(dataset_a.c.values)
dataset_b_reindexed = dataset_b.reindex(c=all_c_levels)
```

now, the reindexed dataset can be reshaped to conform to the shape of `dataset_a.c`:

```py
In [6]: dataset_b_reindexed.sel(c=dataset_a.c)
Out[6]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (a: 3, b: 4)
Coordinates:
    c        (a, b) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
  * a        (a) int64 0 1 2
  * b        (b) int64 0 1 2 3
Data variables:
    z        (a, b) float64 0.01966 nan 0.9533 0.6805 ... 0.965 nan nan 0.3934
```

There are some nans in there, as we had to add new levels which weren't previously in `dataset_b`. You can do whatever you like with these, e.g. with [`xr.Dataset.fillna`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.fillna.html). But the data is now in a shape that can be broadcast against `dataset_a`:

```py
In [8]: xr.merge([dataset_a, dataset_b_reindexed.sel(c=dataset_a.c)])
Out[8]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (a: 3, b: 4)
Coordinates:
  * a        (a) int64 0 1 2
  * b        (b) int64 0 1 2 3
    c        (a, b) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
Data variables:
    x        (a, b) float64 0.2485 0.45 0.4109 0.2603 ... 0.4866 0.965 0.3934
    y        (a, b) float64 0.07956 0.3514 0.1636 ... 0.2478 0.6228 0.1424
    z        (a, b) float64 0.01966 nan 0.9533 0.6805 ... 0.965 nan nan 0.3934
```

Using DataArrays in selection, covered in the [More Advanced Indexing](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#more-advanced-indexing) section of the User Guide, is one of the more powerful features of xarray that I use constantly. I think it's worth committing it to memory and really focusing on some of the stranger reshape use cases (like the one you have here) because it's a feature of xarray that is truly unique - it's hard to do this in both pandas and numpy and xarray really knocks this out of the park!

Comment: Thank you! That looks a lot nicer than my workaround. Xarray keeps surprising me with its capabilities.